# Bash comparisons with blank variable in simple nmap script

Tags: bash, nmap

I have a simple script that nmaps from a list of ip's, and returns any ips that have port 80 open. The problem is when 80 is closed, instead of no return, Im getting "=: command not found" as it is attempting to compare a blank/empty variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in$(cat filename.txt); do
 str=$(nmap $i |grep 80 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
  if($str = "open"); then
   echo port 80 on $i is open
  fi
done
```

When port 80 is closed, $str is getting nothing for a value, then when I try to compare nothing to the string "open", im getting "=: command not found". How do I check if $str has a value before comparing it to a string? I tried

```
if (! -z $str); then
```

which I thought meant

```
if $str is not null, then,
```

but could not get it to work properly. I certainly believe I understand why its is behaving as it is, I just dont know how to correct it.

Comment: Are you aware that the test command is not `(` in the shell? Are you aware that white space matters and `in$(cat)` does not work? And neither does `if(`.

Comment: I suggest to replace `if($str = "open");` by `if [[ $str = "open" ]];`.

Comment: Jens - in$(cat) definitely works. for i in$(cat file.txt); do echo $i works                            -Cyrus I no longer get the "command not found" but now I no longer get an echo when the port is open

Comment: @johnnystetson what shell are you using? `for i in$(cat file.txt)` gives me an error message (`syntax error near unexpected token 'in$(cat file.txt)'`) in bash versions 2.05b.0(1)-release, 3.2.57(1)-release, and 4.3.39(1)-release. Note that if you run the script with something like `sh scriptname`, you may not be using bash at all.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Im running 4.2.37(1)-release and not using bourne shell

Comment: @johnnystetson No it doesn't. There must be a space after `in`.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

port="80"

while read -r host; do
  str=$(nmap "$host" -p "$port" | grep "^$port")
  ret="${PIPESTATUS[0]}"    # returncode of nmap

  if [[ $ret != 0 ]]; then
    echo "error"
    exit 1
  fi

  # check if $str contains "open"
  if [[ $str =~ open ]]; then
    echo "port $port on $host is open"
  else
    echo "port $port on $host is not open"
  fi
done <filename.txt
```

I assume filename.txt contains only one IP or hostname per line.

Output (example):

```
port 80 on 10.20.30.40 is not open
port 80 on localhost is open
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using netcat's exit status:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read host; do
    nc -zw2 $host 80 &>/dev/null && state=open || state=closed
    echo "port 80 on $host is $state"
done < filename.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for the help, Cyrus I like yours a lot, better than what I came up with, and Cole I was very happy to see it done with netcat. Here is what I eventually arrived at

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in$(cat targetlist.txt); do    --multiple people say this doesnt work
str=$(nmap -p 80 $i | grep 80 | cut -d ' ' -f2)   --im using bash 4.2.37(1)
if [[ ! -z $str && $str = "open" ]] ; then
echo port 80 on $i is open
fi
done
```